# Creating dynamic SQL for a lot of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

I am trying to find out differences between two tables (IAM and IAM_audit) for the last modified date for a lot of audit_fields(around 20). I am just showing two audit_fields here. If I use cursors, it's slow. Here is the example of two columns. Please help me on how to create a single dynamic query instead to give results together? Thanks a lot!

Table creation:

```
create table #Iam
(
      Accnum int,
      invnumber int,
      name varchar(10),
      Ac_status varchar(10)
)

insert into #Iam (Accnum, invnumber, name, Ac_status)
values (120, 131, 'abc', 'A'), (121, 132, 'def', 'C')

create table #Iam_audit
(
     accnum int,
     invnumber int,
     audit_field varchar(10),
     field_after varchar(10),
     modified_date datetime
)

insert into #Iam_audit (accnum, invnumber, audit_field, field_after, modified_date)
values (120, 131, 'name', 'abd', '2014-08-09'),
       (121, 132, 'ac_status', 'A', '2015-07-09'),
       (120, 131, 'name', 'def', '2014-09-15'),
       (121, 132, 'ac_status', 'A', '2015-09-14')
```

Separate queries:

```
SELECT 
    a.invnumber, a.Accnum,
    i.audit_field, i.field_after, name, i.maxdate AS Modified_date
FROM 
    #Iam a
JOIN 
    (SELECT
         a.invnumber, a.Accnum, a.field_after, audit_field, maxdate
     FROM
         #Iam_audit a WITH(nolock)
     INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
              Accnum, invnumber, MAX(Modified_Date) AS maxdate
          FROM
              #Iam_audit a2 WITH(nolock)
          WHERE
              a2.Audit_field = 'name'
          GROUP BY
              Accnum, invnumber) AS aa ON aa.Accnum = a.Accnum 
                                       AND aa.invnumber = a.invnumber 
                                       AND aa.maxdate = a.modified_Date
    WHERE
        a.Audit_Field = 'name') i ON i.audit_field = 'name'  
                                  AND i.Accnum = a.Accnum 
                                  AND i.invnumber = a.invnumber  
                                  AND a.name <> i.field_after

SELECT a.invnumber,a.Accnum,i.audit_field,i.field_after,ac_status,i.maxdate as Modified_date
FROM #Iam a
JOIN (Select  a.invnumber,a.Accnum,  a.field_after,audit_field,maxdate
from #Iam_audit a(nolock)
inner join (Select Accnum,invnumber, max(Modified_Date) as maxdate
        from #Iam_audit a2(nolock)
        where a2.Audit_field='ac_status'
        group by Accnum,invnumber
        ) as aa  on aa.Accnum = a.Accnum and aa.invnumber=a.invnumber and aa.maxdate=a.modified_Date
        where a.Audit_Field='ac_status') i
ON i.audit_field='ac_status'  and i.Accnum=a.Accnum and i.invnumber=a.invnumber  AND a.name<>i.field_after
```

Comment: I have spent quite a bit of time looking at this and I just don't get what you are trying to do. I see the queries you put together to get the data you want but I just can't unravel it. Can you explain what this is attempting to accomplish? I have a general idea but the details are escaping me.

Comment: Hello Sean,  I have two table IAM and IAM_audit, I am trying to find any differences that IAM_audit table did not capture from IAM for the last modifed_Date for the audit fields. The columns in IAM are audit fields in IAM_audit that is been monitored. Now to find every differences between two tables usually is okay. however in this case, one table they are columns and in another table it is a field...so when i tried cursor..it got slow..so thought how to use dynamic SQL for this...am i clear :) now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short description of the solution:

1. Create a cursor for the table column names
2. Plug each column name in a predefined statement
3. Execute the statement

The predefined statement uses a `cross apply` to fetch the most recent audit record.

Full solution:

```
declare @colName nvarchar(50);
declare @stmt nvarchar(500);

DECLARE colNameCur CURSOR FOR
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Iam' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo';

OPEN colNameCur;

FETCH NEXT FROM colNameCur   
INTO @colName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    SET @stmt = 
    'select a.InvNumber, a.AccNum, ''' + @colName + ''' as audit_field, last_audit.field_after, a.Name, last_audit.modified_date
    from Iam a
    cross apply (  select top 1 aa.field_after, aa.modified_date
                   from Iam_audit aa
                   where aa.AccNum = a.AccNum
                     and aa.InvNumber = a.InvNumber
                     and aa.audit_field = ''' + @colName + '''
                     and aa.field_after <> a.' + @colName + '
                   order by aa.modified_date desc ) last_audit';

  exec (@stmt);

   FETCH NEXT FROM colNameCur   
   INTO @colName;
END

CLOSE colNameCur;
DEALLOCATE colNameCur;
```

Comment: Thank  you, Sander. this is the solution i got too unfortunately :( but takes a lot of time to execute this. I heard we could unpivot pivot the table..Not sure how to do that ...

Comment: @suki Sorry for the misunderstanding. Looping some field names with cursors should not be that slow. I will updated my answer with a new query that should be faster. Result validation through [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f8e4/7).

Comment: No worried and no sorries. Thank you so much!! I am trying as well. Will be waiting!

Comment: The answer has been updated. It's hard to evaluate its performance without a full data set.

Comment: This is good. I used similar query. except that ..its stil slow :) But its alright! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, that I did nto really get what you need, some sort of column-based compare...

The following makes use of XML's abilities to deal with unknown column names on string base:

### edit: simplified

```sql
SELECT  ia.accnum
       ,ia.invnumber
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ia.accnum,ia.invnumber ORDER BY ia.modified_date DESC) SortIndex
       ,ia.modified_date
       ,ia.audit_field
       ,ia.field_after
       ,(
            SELECT * 
            FROM #Iam AS i
            WHERE i.accnum=ia.accnum AND i.invnumber=ia.invnumber  
            FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
        ).query(N'/row/*[lower-case(local-name())=lower-case(sql:column("ia.audit_field"))]')
         .value('(//text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CurrentValue
FROM #Iam_audit AS ia;
```

Some explanation

You pick the rows of your audit-table. The *correlated sub-query* is transfered into an XML. In short: You will get the corresponding row of `#Iam` as an XML (with all columns how many there may are)...

Against this XML you can use an `XQuery` predicate to pick the column correlated to the string in 'audit_field` (this is where the magic happens).

The query returns a sorted set of your audit table **together with the fitting value** of the main table

```
+--------+-----------+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| accnum | invnumber | inx | modified_date           | audit_field | field_after | CurrentValue |
+--------+-----------+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 120    | 131       | 1   | 2014-09-15 00:00:00.000 | name        | def         | abc          |
+--------+-----------+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 120    | 131       | 2   | 2014-08-09 00:00:00.000 | name        | abd         | abc          |
+--------+-----------+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 121    | 132       | 1   | 2015-09-14 00:00:00.000 | ac_status   | A           | C            |
+--------+-----------+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| 121    | 132       | 2   | 2015-07-09 00:00:00.000 | ac_status   | A           | C            |
+--------+-----------+-----+-------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

This won't be fast, but it will be faster than a `CURSOR`...

### UPDATE

It should be faster to pre-create the XML and join them into the query. Especially if there are many rows per `accnum/invnumber`:

```
CREATE TABLE #XMLLookup(accnum INT, invnumber INT, TheXml XML, CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY(accnum,invnumber));
INSERT INTO #XMLLookup
SELECT accnum
      ,invnumber
      ,(SELECT *
        FROM #Iam AS ia2
        WHERE ia.accnum=ia2.accnum
          AND ia.invnumber=ia2.invnumber
        FOR XML PATH('row'))
FROM #Iam AS ia;


SELECT  ia.accnum
       ,ia.invnumber
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ia.accnum,ia.invnumber ORDER BY ia.modified_date DESC) AS inx
       ,ia.modified_date
       ,ia.audit_field
       ,ia.field_after
       ,xl.TheXml
         .query(N'/row/*[lower-case(local-name())=lower-case(sql:column("ia.audit_field"))]')
         .value('(//text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CurrentValue
FROM #Iam_audit AS ia
INNER JOIN #XMLLookup AS xl ON ia.accnum=xl.accnum
                           AND ia.invnumber=xl.invnumber
```